# Swapping characters pairs in a string

Tags: c#, strings, array

I have to swap the characters in a string before sending said string to a device to show the information sent through a LCD, the method I developed is as follows:

```
private string StringSwap(string stringToSwap)
{
    if ((stringToSwap.Length % 2).Equals(1))
    {
        stringToSwap += " ";
    }

    char[] array = stringToSwap.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 2)
    {
        char temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = temp;
    }
    return new string(array);
}
```

I want to know if there are any implementations that do this already (I feel like I am reinventing the wheel here) or, in case there is not, know how to optimize and make this code more resilient, while also making it more readable.

Also, should I make this an extension for the `string` class instead of a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it as an extension. It helps to properly name all the steps:

```
static class StringSwap
{
    public static string Swap(this string text) =>
        new string(text
            ?.PadToEvenLength()
            ?.SwapOddEvenChars()
            ?.ToArray());

    static string PadToEvenLength(this string text) =>
        text.Length.IsOdd() ? text + ' ' : text;

    static IEnumerable<char> SwapOddEvenChars(this string text) =>
        text.Select((c, i) => i.IsOdd() ? text[i - 1] : text[i + 1]);

    static bool IsOdd(this int number) => 
        number % 2 == 1;        
}
```

Comment: I like a lot of things with this code - it's a good solution but there are a couple of problems IMO: `((string)null).Swap()` results in a NRE. Implicit access modifiers and poorly name parameters (arguably a non-issue).

Comment: @RobH can you further explain the problem you see?

Comment: @RobH fixed (except `implicit access modifiers` - it is a definitely way to go for me. The best possible code is the code that does not exist :)

Comment: @RobH Agreed. It looks to me like somebody desparately wanted to use C#'s new features for the sake of using them at the expense of proper error identification. For those reading this that didn't guess NRE = `NullReferenceException`. Although personally I think it should be a `NullArgumentException`, but extension methods are a bit of an odd case.

Comment: @DmitryNogin Personally I don't like your `SwapOddEvenChars` method's implementation because the variable `c` is unused. If you want to do this in a linq style you would probably be better off  doing `Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length).Select(i => i.IsOdd ? text[i - 1] : text[i + 1]);` since it better describes the algorithm being used.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't run the code, but are you sure it does as you expect it to for odd length strings? By padding the last character with a space, you get some... *interesting* results.

For example, inputting `"foo"` will return `"of o"`. That doesn't seem quite right to me. I would expect it to return `"ofo"`.  I would do something like this.

```
private string StringSwap(string stringToSwap)
{
    char[] array = stringToSwap.ToCharArray();

    // even size strings iterate the whole array
    // odd size strings stop one short 
    int offset = (stringToSwap.Length % 2)
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - offset; i += 2)
    {
        char temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = temp;
    }
    return new String(array);
}
```

Essentially, when the mod of 2 equals zero, the code behaves exactly like yours does now, but when the mod of 2 equals one, the loop exits one iteration early, avoiding the `IndexOutOfRangeException` that prompted you to hack in that white space.

Also note that I changed

```
    return new string(array);
```

To

```
     return new String(array);
```

It's terribly picky and pedantic, but I find it poor form to use the `string` alias when you're using it as a class. Seeing a ctor called on a camelCased identifier just looks weird to me. Same goes for things like `string.Empty`. But, like I said, that's just me being nit picky and pedantic. It's not actually a problem.

Comment: That would be the right way to go to and I will take that correction you said about odd strings, but the device will always expect an even length string, that is the reason for padding the string to an even length. About being pedantic and nit picky, don't be afraid to be, at least on me, I always want to improve how I write my code and how it looks to other programmers.

Comment: Ahh. Gotchya. That's kind of an *odd* contract. [ba dum tiss]

Comment: @RubberDuck To balance the argument, I disagree with your changing `string` to `String`. It's a matter of preference so it doesn't matter either way, but as what the OP has used was not technically incorrect or widely accepted as bad practice it shouldn't have been altered.

Comment: Fair @Pharap. I did call it out as a nitpick, but I do consider it bad practice personally, as it hinders readability in my opinion.

Comment: Also your function fails if passed `null`, but presumably error checking was 'left as an exercise for the reader'.

Comment: Yes, it was @Pharap. Although, being a private method, I'd recommend an assert.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, an excuse to use the Zip extension method:

```
private static string StringSwap2(string stringToSwap)
{
    if ((stringToSwap.Length % 2).Equals(1))
    {
        stringToSwap += " ";
    }

    var evens = stringToSwap.Where((w, i) => i % 2 == 0);
    var odds = stringToSwap.Where((w, i) => i % 2 == 1);

    var zipped = evens.Zip(odds, (left, right) => string.Concat(right, left));

    return string.Concat(zipped);
}
```

Comment: Evidently I need to brush up on my functional techniques, totally missed that one.

Comment: Very cool! But this will iterate the list twice, instead of once, right?

Comment: @RubberDuck Sadly yes. Functional programming might be elegant but there is usually a processing cost. Shame there's no 'unzip' function that separates the list into two first :P

Comment: @RubberDuck, true, but I can still claim that the algorithm is O(N)   :)

Comment: True, but there are different degrees of O(N). =)

Answer (score 1):

As a slightly different approach:

```
public class StringHelper
{
    private static void SwapChars(ref char a, ref char b)
    {
        char c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    public static string StringSwap(string stringToSwap)
    {
        if (stringToSwap == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stringToSwap");
        }

        char[] array = stringToSwap.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i += 2)
        {
            StringHelper.SwapChars(ref array[i], ref array[i + 1]);
        }

        return new string(array);
    }
}
```

The other answers are also correct, but I wanted to present a more traditional alternative.

Also I wanted to intoduce handling `null` as an exception. Trying to swap a `null` should generally be treated as an error condition. You may decide that for the sake of simplicity you want to convert a null argument to an empty string or make it return `null`, that's up to you, but whatever you do you should explicitly handle it as an edge-case.

First note that I have changed `i < array.Length` to `i < array.Length - 1`, which has the side effect of making the loop stop short of the final char in a string with an odd length. This behaviour may not be obvious at first so you may prefer to comment or use a variation of one of the other answers to make the behaviour more explicit, but this solution is somewhat more concise than explicit handling of the case where the length is odd.

I chose to make `charSwap` its own function as a means of separating concerns and making the `charSwap` function available to future helper functions that may need the functionality, particularly if you are planning to create other string swapping functions with variations on the behaviour of this one.

Comment: All methods should be `PascalCase` in C#. `charSwap` -> `CharSwap`. It would also be better named as `SwapCharacters`.

Comment: @RobH I made a compromise edit. I'm sure not all conventions forbid private methods being camel-cased, but I usually go by what MSDN says and on this one I can't find anything specific but the general conventions imply all methods should be pascal-cased, so I'll run with that. It's been a while since I've done C# properly, I've been primarily using C++ for the last few weeks/months.

Comment: The "official" [capitalization guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) don't differentiate method casing based on scope. Although I think any *consistent* style is fine, most people around CR use Microsoft's style guide.

Comment: @RubberDuck Those are the 'general conventions' I was referring to.

Comment: Yeah. It's a bit ambiguous @Pharap, but PascalCase regardless of scope is "the standard" for methods.